# bootstrap.js type error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an error in my site. The error is :

> Timestamp: 10/17/2012 8:27:23 PM
>   Error: TypeError: $ is not a function
>   Source File: path to my site/js/bootstrap.js
>   Line: 23

If this is a conflict with some other jQuery file, how I can remove it?

Comment: Make sure you are including jQuery first, and then including bootstrap.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you're missing jQuery. Make sure you include it in your page before including Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

is your writing order right like above?